# Pixel Drawing Library

Tags: c++, drawing, pixel

A few years ago I used a simple display/pixel drawing library in C++ to display the results of a software rasteriser I'd made and I'm trying to find it again but with no luck. I have a feeling the library had those two words in the name (or one of them).

You would create your own buffers then pass the `display` class the buffer and it would display it in the window, with some relatively high performance as far as I could remember.

The buffer could be in various formats, from 32 bit float to 8-bit ARGB integer. It was only a small selection of classes mainly to do with getting your image buffer onto it's own window.

Has anyone ever used this library? It's not CImg which is larger.

Comment: Assuming (since you're concerned with size) that it's not SDL? The other one I know of is Pixel Toaster.

Comment: Pixel Toaster! That's it. Thank you LaceySnr.

Comment: The correct website to download is http://code.google.com/p/pixeltoaster/ for reference.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was just looking around for a link :) Need to check that out myself.

Comment: Do you want post this as the answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming (since you're concerned with size) that it's not SDL? The other one I know of is [Pixel Toaster](http://code.google.com/p/pixeltoaster/).

Answer (score 0):

The Pixel Toaster just can't compile with Xcode 6.1 under OS X 10.10.1